# Apex Test Class for Invocablemethods

Tags: salesforce, apex, test-class, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

I'm brand new to writing apex and especially test classes in apex. I can’t seem to find out how to properly call my class method in my test class it seems like. My test class is definitely not finished but I'm just starting with one of my delete methods.

I seem to be getting stuck on line 17 on my test class “CreateQuoteProducts_OtherOpp.DeleteQuoteProductsOTFOther(testQPOTF.id);” I’m getting an error that states:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void DeleteQuoteProductsOTFOther(Id) from the type CreateQuoteProducts_OtherOpp

I think I just need to pass in the OrderId but I’m not too sure what I’m doing wrong.

This is my apex class

```
public class CreateQuoteProducts_OtherOpp{
    @invocableMethod
    public static void DeleteQuoteProductsMRFOther(List<Id> OrderId){
        List<Quote_Product_MRF__c> QuoteProductsMRFOther = [SELECT id from Quote_Product_MRF__c WHERE Order__c in : OrderId];
        if(!QuoteProductsMRFOther.isEmpty()){
            delete QuoteProductsMRFOther;
        }
    }
    public static void DeleteQuoteProductsOTFOther(List<Id> OrderId){
        List<Quote_Product__c> QuoteProductsOTFOther = [SELECT id from Quote_Product__c WHERE Order__c in : OrderId];
        if(!QuoteProductsOTFOther.isEmpty()){
            delete QuoteProductsOTFOther;
        }
    }
/* ---START--- Create Quote Products MRF ---START--- */
    public void CreateQuoteProductsMRFOther(List<Id> OrderId){
        List<AggregateResult> nrqpmrfOPOther = [
        SELECT 
        count(Id) ct,
        Order__c ord,
        sum(Total_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c) stmr,
        sum(Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c) mr,
        sum(Discount_MRF__c) dmr
        FROM Order_Location_Package__c 
        WHERE Order__c in : OrderId AND Package__r.Monthly_Recurring_Price__c != null AND Package_Status__c = 'New'
        GROUP BY Package__c, Order__c];
        List<Quote_Product_MRF__c> nrqpmrfOther = New List<Quote_Product_MRF__c>();
        for(AggregateResult ar : nrqpmrfOPOther){
        Quote_Product_MRF__c QuoteProductMRF = New Quote_Product_MRF__c();
        QuoteProductMRF.Quantity__c = (Decimal)ar.get('ct');
        QuoteProductMRF.Order__c = (String)ar.get('ord');
        QuoteProductMRF.Total_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('stmr');
        QuoteProductMRF.Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('mr');
        QuoteProductMRF.Discount_MRF__c = (Decimal)ar.get('dmr');
        QuoteProductMRF.Product_Type__c = 'Package';
        nrqpmrfOther.add(QuoteProductMRF);
        } 
        Insert nrqpmrfOther;
    }
/* ---END--- Create Quote Products MRF ---END--- */
/* ---START--- Create Quote Products OTF ---START--- */
    public void CreateQuoteProductsOTFOther(List<Id> OrderId){
        List<AggregateResult> nrqpotfOPOther = [
        SELECT 
        count(Id) ct,
        Order__c ord,
        sum(Total_One_Time_Fees__c) stmr,
        sum(One_Time_Fees__c) mr,
        sum(Discount_OTF__c) dmr
        FROM Order_Location_Package__c 
        WHERE Order__c in : OrderId AND Package__r.One_Time_Price__c != null AND Package_Status__c = 'New'
        GROUP BY Package__c, Order__c];
        List<Quote_Product__c> nrqpotfOther = New List<Quote_Product__c>();
        for(AggregateResult ar : nrqpotfOPOther){
        Quote_Product__c QuoteProductOTF = New Quote_Product__c();
        QuoteProductOTF.Quantity__c = (Decimal)ar.get('ct');
        QuoteProductOTF.Order__c = (String)ar.get('ord');
        QuoteProductOTF.Total_One_Time_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('stmr');
        QuoteProductOTF.One_Time_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('mr');
        QuoteProductOTF.Discount_OTF__c = (Decimal)ar.get('dmr');
        QuoteProductOTF.Product_Type__c = 'Package';
        nrqpotfOther.add(QuoteProductOTF);
        } 
        Insert nrqpotfOther;
    }
/* ---END--- Create Quote Products ORD ---END--- */
}
```

And this is my test class I’m writing

```
@isTest
private class CreateQuoteProducts_OtherOppTest {
    private static testMethod void doTest() {
        Order_Sheet__c testOrder  = new Order_Sheet__c ();
                testOrder.Opportunity__c = 'Opportunity';
                insert testOrder;
        
Test.startTest();
        /* --- Create Quote Product OTF--- */
        Quote_Product__c testQPOTF  = new Quote_Product__c ();
                testQPOTF.Order__c = testOrder.id;
                
                insert testQPOTF;

        /* --- Run Delete Method--- */
        CreateQuoteProducts_OtherOpp.DeleteQuoteProductsOTFOther(testQPOTF.id);
        
        /* --- Query for QP OTF--- */
        list<Quote_Product__c>queriedQPOTF = [Select Id FROM Quote_Product__c WHERE Order__c = :testOrder.id];
        
        /* --- Checks for 0 records --- */
        system.assertEquals(0, queriedQPOTF.size());

        Test.stopTest();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public static void DeleteQuoteProductsOTFOther(List<Id> OrderId)` accepts list of Ids. You try to pass a single Id: `CreateQuoteProducts_OtherOpp.DeleteQuoteProductsOTFOther(testQPOTF.id);`

It's like "array of integers" and "one integer" are not compatible types. If you will not need that list for anything else you can create it in-flight and it'll be then discarded when that line of code finishes:

`CreateQuoteProducts_OtherOpp.DeleteQuoteProductsOTFOther(new List<Id>{testQPOTF.id});`

This should compile fine

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the explanation. All is compiling now.  Appreciate your help!